# Is there a component in camel for a service built on Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: spring-mvc, apache-camel, resttemplate

I have a REST Service running in Tomcat server. I created this REST Service using Spring RESTTemplate. So is there a component in CAMEL to use this exposed Web service?

i have used http component. i am aware that we cannot use http component to expose a service. So please let me know which component to use.Here is a detailed description of the problem.

Service created in rest Template runs in a server which you can see in from part of camel code

i use camel to expose this service to another http service  and the response of this service is the response from the other service.

so my camel code looks like this:

```
    from("http://localhost:8080/rest/emp/dummy").to(http://anotherweservice.com")
```

I get this error.

**Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[]] -> [process[com.routes.....    because of uri must be specified and not empty**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-camel-as-a-http-proxy-between-a-client-and-server.html.

Using the Jetty component, this looks as follows:

```
from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8080/myapp?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
    .log("myapp: httpPath = ${header.CamelHttpPath}")
    .to("jetty:http://localhost:8082/remoteapp?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
```

In this example, the request is forwarded to another Jetty Camel endpoint:

```
from("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8082/remoteapp?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
     .log("remoteapp: httpPath = ${header.CamelHttpPath}")
     .setBody(simple("${header.CamelHttpPath}"));
```

The HTTP path `/hello/world` is transfered to the endpoint, as can be seen when the service is invoked with `http://localhost:8080/myapp/hello/world`. In this case the body `/hello/world` is returned. And in the log it says:

```
INFO  myapp: httpPath = /hello/world
INFO  remoteapp: httpPath = /hello/world
```

Comment: peter my another web service is a service thats hitting the internet. So the second option should work right?

Comment: Thanks its working. but tell me how to get the parameter from the exposed service. Say i have a service from(servlet:myapp/{rest}/{emp} and i want to pass it in to address.i am getting a 404 error. as it accepts only servlet:myapp/{rest}/{emp} not (servlet:myapp/hello/123) i am getting a 404 error

Comment: @bks4line The Jetty component is also fine if you hit the internet and I guess the configuration is simpler then the servlet solution. The HTTP path is preserved as can be seen in my updated answer.

Comment: But can you propose me a solution in servlet. I have some class loading issuses when i work with Jetty in Web Sphere RSA. It will be really helpful if you can suggest me a solution with camel Servlet. Thanks!